# .click show alert from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a button and text box that reads an id for a specific user on my json file. If the user enters 001 their name will appear on the alert, the alert is hidden on page load but when the user enters this information the alert shows - Welcome (users name and details from the json file)

This script works, however when I wait a few seconds it disappears, how so I get it to stay on the page when it appears?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Hide alert when page loads
$("#loginalert").hide();    
$("#loginbtn").click(function(event){
//console.log("clicked login");
   $.getJSON('result.json', function(jd) {
      var id = $('#userName').val();
      //console.log(id);
      for (var i=0; i<jd.user.length; i++) {
        if (jd.user[i].ID == id) {
          $('#loginalert').html('<p> Welcome: ' + jd.user[i].name + '</p>');      
          //show the alert after loading the information
            $("#loginalert").stop().fadeIn('slow').animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 3000).fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $('#contact').fadeIn('slow');
        });
        }
      }
   });
}); });
```

also is there any way to add like a slide down or slide up animation when he alert box appears?

Alert box:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" id="loginalert"> <strong>Welcome!</strong></div>
```

The login box that requires the user to enter their ID:

```
div class="alert alert-info">
<input type="text" id="userName" value> <button type="button" id="loginbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Login</button></div>
```

this now works if i take away the fade out

Is there any way to display the message

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
<strong>Danger!</strong> Indicates a dangerous or potentially negativeaction.</div>
```

if a user enters an invalid id or enters nothing?

many thanks

Comment: What's the position of loginalert? absolute or relative?

Comment: Hi, since the answer provides a working solution, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `fadeOut()` part. That code is responsible for hiding it again.

Comment: thanks Johannes Jander! this worked.. I didnt think it was as simple as that   - if I had an error message to appear instead of the `<div class="alert alert-success" id="loginalert"> <strong>Welcome!</strong></div>   -for instance a <div class="alert alert-danger">
  `<strong>Error</strong> Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action.</div>`   if the user enterd nothin or an invalid how would I modify my code to get this to appear?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    //Hide alert when page loads
    var alertBox=$("#loginalert");
    alertBox.hide();    
    $("#loginbtn").on('click',function(e){
        //  console.log("clicked login");
        e.preventDefault();
        $.getJSON('result.json', function(jd) {
            var id = $('#userName').val();
            // console.log(id);
            for (var i=0; i<jd.user.length; i++) {
                if (jd.user[i].ID == id) {
                   // show the alert if d.user[i].ID is idafter
                    var message= "<p> Welcome: ' + jd.user[i].name + '</p>'";
                    alertBox.html(message).fadeIn('slow',function(){
                        $('#contact').fadeIn('slow')
                    })
                } else {
                    // show the alert if d.user[i].ID is not idafter
                    var message= "<p> Error </p>'";
                    alertBox.html(message).fadeIn('slow')
                }
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: Hi vixed, thank you for your answer, this was hidden on show, however when i entered a correct user's id error displaed

Comment: what do you mean saying **this was hidden on show** ?